# How to choose system to boot up without monitor?

Tags: bootloader

I have Raspberry with Raspbian and RaspBMC (installed from NOOBS).

I use Raspbian without monitor, keyboard and mouse at my workshop. SSH, apache and samba is all I need to interact with PI there.

Sometimes I take my Pi to use it at home with RaspBMC. I connect it to TV and mouse.

Sometimes I forgot reboot Raspberry and choose Raspbian to use Raspbian at workshop and I end with XBMC.

The question is:

**Where "last operating system used" is stored? How can I reboot into Raspbian when RaspBMC is running?**

I have SSH enabled on XBMC.

Comment: Have a look at /boot/config.txt

Comment: Get one more pi. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Berryboot[1]. It's a bootloader that can install more than one OS into an USB flash disk. Berryboot has a feature like VNC to boot screen this could be what you want. You can connect through VNC when RPi booting, at this screen you can choose into OS what you want to boot.

I'm using Berryboot with 3 OS installed. PiBang[2] as desktop with GUI, Moebious as server, Xbian as media server. At the boot sequence i can choose what OS going to boot.

[1] http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot
[2] http://pibanglinux.org
[3] http://moebiuslinux.sourceforge.net
[4] http://www.xbian.org